# %matplotlib qt or tk in jupyter notebook in vscode

Tags: qt, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When using plt.show() inside a jupyter cellnusing vscode with %matplotlib qt the image window appears, but the image is not drawn in the window until the cell exits. This is a problem because I want to loop and display a series of images.
With %matplotlib tk, the window does not appear, but when the cell finishes, all of the tk windows appear.

Here is a code snippet:

```
response =''
for image, label in zip(image_files, label_files):
    image_path = image
    annotation_path = label
    figure = display_image_with_annotations(image_path, annotation_path)
    
    response = input('q to quit, anyother key to continue')
    print('response: ',response)
    if response == 'q':
        break
    plt.close(fig = figure)
```

The function display_image_with_annotations(image_path, annotation_path) does the image display (it has the plt.show() command, and with %matplotlib inline it works fine.

This code works as a regular python program with a tk or qt window. It loops, displays an image, waits for a character input, and if it is not q, then it closes the open figure and displays a new image window.

All of this is in vscode.
Supplementary info:
os: POP OS 22.04
Gnome shell version 42.5, hybrid graphics mode.

Can someone tell me how to do this as a Jupyter script in vscode?